# Dreamweaver CS6 for mac

Tags: macos, adobe

Dose any one know the shortcut key for opening a file from the "files" browser?

I tried Command+O but that open the location in finder instead of dreamweaver.

Or how to change it to the enter key?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Cmd+O when the Dreamweaver is active ? Because it is working in my Mac.

Comment: Yes I am. Might be a setting in Dreamweaver

Answer (score 1):

Ive look at the shortcuts tab and found nothing for the files window.
[image: Files Sidebar window]

Cmd+O opens the finder file window, and lets you press enter there.
Im asking if there is a shortcut for the files sidebar window?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shortcut key for File>Open.

Click on Dreamweaver Menu. Select Keyboard Shortcuts. Then you will get a window as shown in the picture. You can change the shortcut there.
[image: Keyboard Shortcuts, DW]